# Parsing of weekdays not working for locale german

Tags: java, locale, date-parsing, java-time

I'm trying to use java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter to parse time strings but ran into a problem parsing german short day of week names.

Given the following program

```java
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.TextStyle;
import java.util.Locale;

var locale = Locale.forLanguageTag("de");
var dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("eeee"))
        .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("eee"))
        .toFormatter(locale);
var input1 = DayOfWeek.TUESDAY.getDisplayName(TextStyle.FULL, locale);
var input2 = DayOfWeek.TUESDAY.getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, locale);
System.out.printf("input: %s, parsed: %s\n", input1, dtf.parse(input1));
System.out.printf("input: %s, parsed: %s\n", input2, dtf.parse(input2));
```

the output I would expect is

```
input: Dienstag, parsed: {DayOfWeek=2},ISO
input: Di, parsed: {DayOfWeek=2},ISO
```

but I actually get

```
input: Dienstag, parsed: {DayOfWeek=2},ISO
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text 'Di' could not be parsed, unparsed text found at index 0
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parseResolved0(DateTimeFormatter.java:2049)
    at java.base/java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1874)
    at org.rksm.Main.main(Main.java:22)
```

Note that when I change the locale to `Locale.forLanguageTag("en")` it works and the output is

```
input: Tuesday, parsed: {DayOfWeek=2},ISO
input: Tue, parsed: {DayOfWeek=2},ISO
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work with [`Locale.GERMANY`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#GERMANY) (or `GERMAN`)?

Comment: Note that `eee` stands for `TextStyle.SHORT`, WHILE `ccc` stands for `TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE`. Have you tried `ccc`?

Comment: RealSkeptic: Indeed, TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE / ccc is the way to go. If you post it as an answer I mark it as such. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although in English there is no difference between the name of the day when it is used alone and the name as it is used within the context of a date, in German, apparently, there is.

The pattern `eee` corresponds to `TextStyle.SHORT`, while the pattern `ccc` corresponds to `TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE`. Thus, if you try to parse a day name that was created by `TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE` with `eee` in the languages where it matters, the parsing will fail.

The way to go is `ccc` for the standalone version.

The documentation mentioning this is actually in the [`DateTimeFormatterBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-) API rather than `DateTimeFormatter`'s.

Comment: That’s true: `TextStyle.SHORT` gives `Di.` with a dot, `SHORT_STANDALONE` just `Di` without the dot (on my Java 11 with default settings; I suspect that setting the system property `java.locale.providers` would change the results).